# receiving reversed data in c socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I want to write a c program that listen to a socket and get payload for a specific TCP protocol and send response. I have a problem in assigning value to response packet fields.

At first i created the protocol packet structures :

```
struct header {
    unsigned int field_1:32;
    unsigned int field_2:32;
    unsigned int field_3:32;
    unsigned int field_4:32;
}

struct request {
    struct header req_hdr;
    char req_body[100];
}


struct response {
    struct header resp_hdr;
    char resp_body[16];
}
```

After the server socket receives a request, it send a response to client. To do that i first create a response structure :

```
struct  response *resp;
resp = calloc (1, sizeof (struct response));
```

Then i fill response packet fields with appropriate value. *resp->header.field_1* must be the length of the body PDU. I assign it in this way :

```
resp->header.field_1=strlen(resp->resp_body);
```

And there is an hexadecimal value that must be assign to  *resp->header.field_2*. i convert this hexadecimal number to integer and then assign it to *resp->header.field_2*. because in the protocol document *resp->header.field_2* must be an integer and not a string. the equivalent integer of 0x80000009 is 2147483657, so i assign it in this way and send it to client:

```
resp->header.field_1=2147483657;
```

I used tshark on client system to check the response that the server are sending back. i get the packet like this :

```
04000000 09000080 00000000 00000001 74657374000000000000000000000000
```

First left byte is *resp->header.field_1* and second is *resp->header.field_2*. **here is the problem** : *resp->header.field_1* must be 00000004 and *resp->header.field_2* must be 80000009 but it seems they are reversed (rest fields are ok) and it's caused the response packet can not be recognized by the client. how can i assign these value to the their fields correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Server program you need to convert response header integers to from host byte stream to network order. You should use `htons()` or `htonl()` on it first. If you're receiving an integer in clinet, you should use `ntohs()` or `ntohl()`.